# C - Why is this string not being assigned to the variable?

Tags: c

I've been trying to understand why my string/char array loses the value assigned to it in the for loop as soon as the loop ends. The value for token2 is a user input that gets shunted into the "token2" variable earlier on in the code. I have several checks prior to this portion and token2 is populated as expected.

```
int dayInt2;
char dayToken2[3];

//For loop to parse out the month portion of second token.
for (int i = 3; i < 5; i++)
{
  dayToken2[i] = token2[i];
  printf("For loop parse: %c\n", token2[i]);
}
dayToken2[3] = '\0'; //Add null pointer to the last character space of the string array.

printf("dayToken2 value: %s\n", dayToken2); //Debugging to check the value in dayToken2.

dayInt2 = atoi(dayToken2); //converts day

printf("dayInt2 value: %s\n", dayInt2); //Debugging to check if the string conversion to int worked.
```

Comment: `dayToken2[i] = token2[i];` and `dayToken2[3] = '\0'` are buffer overflows. The valid indices for a three element array is `0`-`2`.

Comment: If you still need further please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67864217/edit) the post to update it with a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is difficult to debug incomplete code snippets.

Comment: What were you trying to achieve by having the index take the values 3 and 4?

Comment: in C, the index into an array starts with 0 and continues to (number of elements in array -1)  so this statement: `dayToken2[3] = '\0';` is writing past the end of the `dayToken[]` array, resulting in undefined behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `dayToken2[3]` is outside the array. The indexes are from zero. So the maximum index is **`2`**.
2. `printf("dayInt2 value: %s\n", dayInt2);` is wrong. You try to print the integer but you say the `printf` that it should expect the string. It has to be `printf("dayInt2 value: %d\n", dayInt2);`
3. `dayToken2[i] = token2[i];` is also wrong as `i` changes from `3` to `4`. It has to be `dayToken2[i - 3] = token2[i];`. You can use `memcpy` for that `memcpy(dayToken2, token2 + 3, 2);`

Comment: Thanks, for reviewing and catching those trivial mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

When defining your char array, you set the max indices as 3, so there is only dayToken[0], dayToken[1], dayToken[2]. In your for loop you set i from 3-5, try doing from 0-2.